# How do I pass a file as an argument in bash scripting?

Tags: bash

I'm a bit confused, so I looked it up, and I found this:

```
FILE1=$1
wc $FILE1
```

this is a bit confusing to me, what does assigning the variable expression operator, followed by the number 1 to FILE1, but FILE1 is just a variable, and we're assigning what? The number 1 to the variable expression operator?

How does this work exactly?

What can I do to better understand this concept?

Comment: How does that make FILE1 a file to be passed onto the script?

Comment: `$1` is the first of the "positional parameters" to a script / program / function, explained in your shell's man page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1 is a variable containing the value of the first argument  passed to the script, so if one ran

> ./myscript myfile

then $FILE1 would be set to myfile

Comment: what if I named it something else? ./626 myfile ?

Comment: Also, is myfile a command in the bash script?

Comment: myfile is an argument, much like you would pass `-l` to the `ls` command. It can be an arbitrary string that you can use for whatever purpose in your script. `$1` references the first argument that comes after calling your script.